# .NET Core 3 API - Stops working after one request?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm having a strange issue where requests only work once. It happens in both IIS and IIS Express. If I restart/recycle, it'll work again, but still just once. Placing a breakpoint reveals subsequent requests never hit the controller...

```
[HttpGet("private/{zipCode}")]
public IActionResult PrivateZipSearch(string zipCode)
```

Startup.Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider srv, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     loggerFactory.AddProvider(new DbLoggerProvider(this.Configuration, srv.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));

     app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // Redirect HTTP -> HTTPS
     app.UseRouting();
     {
         app.UseCors(Config.Settings.Cors.PolicyName);
         app.UseAuthentication();
     }

     // Hangfire
     {
         app.UseHangfireDashboard();
         app.UseHangfireServer();
     }

     app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>();
     app.UseMiddleware<OptionsVerbMiddleware>();

     // Must be last!
     app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapControllers());
 }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Stop working as in the IIS app stops? What are the response codes from the first and second request? Are there any clues in the log?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @RuardvanElburg. IIS doesn't stop and response codes are all 200. The log doesn't offer anything useful.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by not working. Can you explain a bit more? If the requests return 200, then what is not working?

Comment: The first request hits the controller and returns the data, subsequent requests do not despite apparently returning 200.

Comment: That would indicate that the pipeline short-circuits, before reaching the controller. Is there a difference between the two requests concerning authorization? Than you can rule that out. From your code there are four potentials middleware, the most likely: HangfireDashboard, HangfireServer and LoggingMiddleware, OptionsVerbMiddleware. Add logging to see which middleware short-circuits or try with disableing / enableing middleware. And also take a look at filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was setting the HttpContext to a field.

There's a bunch of do's and don'ts, which can be found here:
https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-store-ihttpcontextaccessorhttpcontext-in-a-field

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Core 3.0 API shut down after I sent a request to it because I had an infinite loop in my repositories, like this:

EmpresaRepository:

```
    public class EmpresaRepository : BaseRepository<Empresa>, IEmpresaRepository
    {
        private readonly EstabelecimentoRepository estabelecimentoRepository;

        public EmpresaRepository(Context Context) : base(Context)
        {
            estabelecimentoRepository = new EstabelecimentoRepository(Context);
        }
    }
```

EstabelecimentoRepository:

```
public class EstabelecimentoRepository : BaseRepository<Estabelecimento>, IEstabelecimentoRepository
{
    private readonly EmpresaRepository empresaRepository;

    public EstabelecimentoRepository(Context Context) : base(Context)
    {
         empresaRepository = new EmpresaRepository(Context);
    }
}
```

So, in `EstabelecimentoRepository` I took out the `empresaRepository` and my API went back to work.